# If there are 3 etcd nodes, will Apache APISIX still be able to get the configuration if 2 of them fail? Why?

Tags: apache-apisix

In order to use APISIX I have prepared an etcd cluster with three nodes, I would like to ask that if two nodes fail, can APSIX still get the configuration normally?
Also if all the nodes fail will APISIX still work?

Answer (score 1):

No, APISIX won't be able to get the configuration if 2 of the 3 nodes fail because etcd runs on the RAFT consensus algorithm to establish consistency in the database. If two of the 3 nodes are unavailable, etcd won't be able to establish a quorum status, thus etcd will become unavailable.